# How do people know what games people are talking about?

Tags: discussion

I saw a question just saying something like "how do I get back to the village", and someone answered it as if he actually posted the name to the game, so how did he know? Are there just that many people here that at least one person recognizes what someone is talking about?

Sorry about posting on the wrong site, I'm new here. :P

Comment: Maybe you didn't see the question tags. It tells which game/platform the asker has a problem so he doesn't have to precise it inside his question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All questions should be tagged with the name of the game (which is how we know what they're about).  It's generally a good idea to have the name of the game somewhere in the question body as well as this helps with SEO, but it's not required.

Sometimes people forget to tag the game, or tag the question incorrectly and it does take some wiggling to figure out what game they're playing!

This is what tags should look like: generally speaking, the fewer the better.

[image: Post title with tags]

You should always tag your post with the name of the game, and if it's *relevant to the question*, the platform you're playing on.

Comment: Note that we also allow questions that do not require a game-tag, such as questions about console features, controllers, gamer-terminology questions etc.